# jvm able to access with eclipse but not with jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I have issue with jvm argument being passed:
1. I can pass jvm argument in eclipse as -Dname=value and access the same through java as system.getproperty("name");
2. But when i try the same with Jenkins, as it is a maven project with multiple pom, not able to pass this param i.e., it shows null on printing it.

Done with lot lot more surfing and tries... but didnt get a fix yet :(

passed param in mvn .. -Dname=value ...
tried with  setting property in pom etc.., nothing helped

Is ther any other way to set system property in global access so that all the pom and java files can access it.

MAVAN_OPTS, jenkins ettings nothing worked...

Answer (score 0):

You can set system variables via the `<systemPropertyVariables>` configuration of maven surfire plugin.

See documentation and full example here:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Comment: actually i tried evn this solution...my issue is that i can set property in pom and access with java code...but when i try to set the same jvm property  from jenkins, it is null...    my project is with multiple pom and also a property set in 1 pom is not visible in other pom....

Comment: Is there any way to set a property in 1 pom and access it across entire maven project which is with multiple poms ..   ' parent-pom-A child-pom-b child-pom-c'          scenario like: setting a system property in A and access it with java of pomC module